# Why are discriminative models denoted as $P\left(Y|X\right)$?

Tags: neural-network, generative-models

In general, we can speak we know deterministic and probabilistic models. Discriminative ones are deterministic, while generative one is probabilistic.

But I have been reading about the difference between discriminative and generative models where the difference was expressed as:

$P\left(Y|X\right)$ for D. models

and $P\left(X|Y\right) \cdot P\left(Y\right)$ for G. models

My question is: Why do we denote $P\left(Y|X\right)$ for Discriminative models, since these models are completely deterministic, build on top of composite functions with no stochastic processes? Isn't this confusing?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. Naive Bayes (generative) is no more probabilistic than, say, Logistic Regression (discriminative).

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/generative-vs-discriminative. Note that determinism has nothing to do with the distinction discriminative vs. generative.

Answer (score 1):

**Discriminative models** output some tensor $Y$ describing a label given some input tensor $X$ describing some input data. The method of mapping $X$ to $Y$ might be deterministic or not - there's no need for it to be (consider the example of taking a deterministic model and adding a small amount of random noise to it, so that it is perhaps $1\%$ less accurate and more random). The accuracy of the model is the average accuracy over the validation/testing data. The model estimates the probability that the label is $Y$ given the input data is $X: P\left(Y|X\right)$.

**Generative models** generate a tensor that is drawn from a learned distribution that is similar (as a result of the learning) to the distribution of some training data. For sequence generation, the probability of a generated tensor ($X$, say) at time t is dependent on the probability that the tensor generated at time step $t-1$ was correct ($P\left(Y\right)$, say) and the probability of the new tensor ($X$) if the previous one is taken as given (probability of $X$ given $Y$, or $P\left(X|Y\right)$). The probability of the recently-generated tensor is $P\left(X|Y\right) \cdot P\left(Y\right)$.

I don't really like the notation in the text you're reading, and I agree with you that it's confusing. However, in answer to your question "Why do we denote $P\left(Y|X\right)$ for Discriminative models": model outputs are *always estimates* and should ideally reflect the fact that the input data doesn't perfectly predict the class. That is, even deterministic models should communicate their estimates in the language of probability; for example even a deterministic model might give an output that can be interpreted as "$80\%$ of the time, input data with these features means the class is C"

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not misleading at all. Without loss of the generality, we can refer to generative and discriminative classifiers.
Both models predict $Y$ on the basis of $X$ in other words they have to model $ P \left( Y | X \right) $, because in the end you give them unseen before input and expect output right?
How can they do it without probability?
They will return output which is the most probable for them.
Doesn't mind that it is deterministic or stochastic.
You calculate probabilities on training data with the usage of *MLE* or *MAP*. Generative models, just use likelihood $ P \left( X | Y \right) $ and prior $ P \left( Y \right) $ to do it (Bayes rule).
To make it more fun, *Naive Bayes*, which is generative model, gives completely deterministic answers.
It learns probabilities $ P \left( X = x | Y \right ) $ and $ P \left( Y \right) $ on the training set, and will always return the same result for given input $X$.